# C# How check if event is executed async

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I am a newbie to events and I am asking myself if a event that gets triggered (from a SDK) is executed on the main thread or async on another.

Can anyone help me how to check this?

This for example gets executed if the event fires and it doesn't block the UI, which surprises me (triggered max. speed each 0.05 seconds):

```
void TrackingOnNewTrackingObservations(object sender, TrackingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            dgvTracking.Rows[0].Cells["cName"].Value = "SlopeDistance";
            dgvTracking.Rows[0].Cells["cValue"].Value = string.Format("{0:0.00} m", e.SlopeDistance);

            dgvTracking.Rows[1].Cells["cName"].Value = "HorizontalAngle";
            dgvTracking.Rows[1].Cells["cValue"].Value = string.Format("{0:0.00000}°", e.HorizontalAngle);

            dgvTracking.Rows[2].Cells["cName"].Value = "VerticalAngle";
            dgvTracking.Rows[2].Cells["cValue"].Value = string.Format("{0:0.00000}°", e.VerticalAngle);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error TrackingOnNewTrackingObservations ->" + ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: `if (dgvTracking.InvokeRequired) {/* Some other thread; use dgvTracking.Invoke(...) to assign dgvTracking properties */} else {/* UI thread */}`

Comment: Async doesn't mean it's on another thread.

Comment: Though it might be depending on the underlying architecture @rory.ap. asp.Net async calls will (potentially) grab a new thread when they return

Comment: OP said "executed on main thread or async on another".  Nothing about when they return.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko the SDK has two implementations to run Tracking. One is called asyn, the other is sync. However, if I implement what you wrote, both jump into the InvokeRequired expression. I am really confused now... . Why did then everything work without invoking?

Comment: @Anon: it seems that you are mixing TPL: `Task`, `async`, `await` and bare `Thread`s. `DoSomethingAsync(...)` returns `Task` which we should `await`; something like `private async void MyEventHandler(object sender, TrackingEventArgs e) {... var result = await DoSomethingAsync(...); ...}`

Comment: @rory.ap I guess my understanding of async is wrong then. But what I was trying to ask was: Is the execution of the showed code snippet done on the main thread or on another thread? Where are those triggers generally executed?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko the SDK does not use Task, async or await. DoSomethingAsync returns a IAsyncResult and needs a callback. However, why are both forms of DoSomethingSync and DoSomethingAsync firing the event on another thread? And why did it work without invoking?

Comment: @Anon: Turn `IAsyncResult` into `Task`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskFactory_FromAsync_System_IAsyncResult_System_Action_System_IAsyncResult__
https://tpodolak.com/blog/2016/02/12/using-asyncawait-iasyncresult-pattern/

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed us this "SDK"s signature.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I can't change anything because it's from a SDK for hardware commands. 

@Liam `IAsyncResult BeginStartTracking (AsyncCallback callback)` for the async method execution and `void StartTracking ()` for the sync. If you meant that...

Answer (score 0):

Use Corewindow.Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess to test whether or not the execution is on the UI thread.

Normally events are going to be invoked on the same thread as the invocation of the method that led to the event. If the class is a UI class them this is going to be the UI thread.

Comment: What I did was: I put `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` into the constructor of one of the UI classes. The Thread ID returned `8`. I also put that line into the method that gets fired by the event and the Thread ID was `9`. So I assume now, it actually creates a new thread, am I correct?

Comment: I agree that they are on different threads. 

Although testing the thread Id seems reasonable, I would really recommend sticking with the pre-defined method, which is HasThreadAccess.

Comment: Well, seems like `CoreWindow.Dispatcher` property is only available in the UWP Framework which I am not using (WinForms .NET 4.0).